# TypeScript type of an async dispatch value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, axios, redux-thunk

I have the following async action definition:

```
import {Dispatch} from 'react';
import axios, {AxiosResponse, AxiosError} from 'axios';

function asyncAction() {
    return (dispatch: Dispatch<any>): Promise<number> => {
        return axios.get('http://www.example.com')
            .then( (res: AxiosResponse<any>) => {
                return 1;
            })
            .catch( (err: AxiosError<any>) => {
                return 2;
            });
    }
}
```

The above typechecks fine.

I also understand that when you call `dispatch` and pass it an asynchronous action, like so:

```
dispatch(asynAction())
```

… then the return type if that of the inner function, so I would expect the type of the above value to be `Promise<number>`. Yet the following does not typecheck:

```
function foo (dispatch: Dispatch<any>) {
    const n: Promise<number> = dispatch(asyncAction()); // line A
}
```

Specifically, I get the following error on `line A`:

```
TS2322: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Promise<number>'
```

So, in order to satisfy TS, I have to do something like the following which feels wrong:

```
const n: Promise<number> = dispatch(asyncAction()) as unknown as Promise<number>;
```

What am I missing?

## update

My `package.json` has:

```
"@types/react-redux": "^7.1.9",
"react-redux": "^7.2.0",
"redux": "^4.0.5",
"redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
```

When I do the following:

```
import {ThunkDispatch as Dispatch} from 'redux-thunk';
```

… and use the imported `ThunkDispatch` type as `ThunkDispatch<any, any, any>` (wherever I have `Dispatch<any>` in the above code), like so:

```
import axios, {AxiosResponse
             , AxiosError} from 'axios';
import {ThunkDispatch as Dispatch} from 'redux-thunk';

export function asyncAction() {
    return (dispatch: Dispatch<any, any, any>): Promise<number> => {
        return axios.get('http://www.example.com')
            .then( (res: AxiosResponse<any>) => {
                return 1;
            })
            .catch( (err: AxiosError<any>) => {
                return 2;
            });
    }
}

export function foo (dispatch: Dispatch<any, any, any>) {
    const n: Promise<number> = dispatch(asyncAction());
    console.log(n);
}
```

… I get a different error:

```
  TS2739: Type '(dispatch: ThunkDispatch<any, any, any>) => Promise<number>' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<number>': then, catch, [Symbol.toStringTag]
```

Comment: `Dispatch<any>` doesn't take a promise. So either the typing is wrong or you're using the lib incorrectly.

Comment: I think you are using the wrong Dispatch. It should be ```import { Dispatch } from "redux"```.

Comment: I think you should import [dispatch type](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/blob/master/src/index.d.ts#L130) from thunk

Comment: @HMR I have `redux-thunk 2.30`, there is no `Dispatch` type there. There is a `ThunkDispatch` type which I imported and used as `ThunkDispatch<any, any, any>` since the type is generic and requires three type arguments (that I've no idea what they stand for). I get a different error message but still no luck. I'll update the question.

Comment: Your `dispatch` method as `dispatch(asynAction())` itself also needs to be typed correctly as `ThunkDispatch`.

Comment: @phry but it is! I just updated the question to show the code that uses the `ThunkDispatch` type

Comment: Could you add a codesandbox? It's hard to see how all that connects, it's a bit chaotic by now.

Comment: It compiles in the first example because `dispatch` is just the argument and you never actually use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different packages have different definitions for the `Dispatch` type.  You are importing the one from 'react', which does not suit your needs.

Redux declares that a dispatch returns the action:

```
export interface Dispatch<A extends Action = AnyAction> {
  <T extends A>(action: T): T
}
```

React, which defines `Dispatch` for the purposes of it's own `useReducer` hook (redux-lite), says that it returns nothing:

```
type Dispatch<A> = (value: A) => void;
```

Thunk has a much more complicated definition which allows it to return any arbitrary return type base on a generic:

```
export interface Dispatch<A extends Action = AnyAction> {
    <TReturnType = any, TState = any, TExtraThunkArg = any>(
      thunkAction: ThunkAction<TReturnType, TState, TExtraThunkArg, A>,
    ): TReturnType;
  }
```

Your first example worked because you never actually called the `dispatch` function and you return type matched the return type from the `axios` call.  You're having the same problem in your second example.

`asyncAction()` doesn't dispatch the action.  `Promise<number>` is the return type *of the action creator*, not of the dispatch.  The error about missing properties is basically telling you that the dispatch doesn't return a `Promise`.

You've written `asyncAction` in a very confused and confusing way, but basically it is a function which returns a function which takes a `dispatch` and returns `Promise<number>`.  So based on that, the way you get `Promise<number>` in `foo` is not by calling `dispatch` with your function, but by passing `dispatch` as the argument to the function created by calling `ayncAction()`.

```
export function foo (dispatch: Dispatch<any, any, any>) {
    const n: Promise<number> = asyncAction()(dispatch);
    console.log(n);
}
```

This of course makes no sense, since you still never dispatch anything anywhere.

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/yNaZ2m)

**Edit:**

Hopefully this helps with what you're tying to do.  Hopefully getting `n` from the return value of the `dispatch` was just for testing because you can't and shouldn't do that.

Let's define the action that we will ultimately dispatch, along with a creator for it.

```
import { Action } from "redux";

// normal action type
interface NumberAction extends Action {
    payload: number;
}

// normal action creator
function sendNumber(number: number): NumberAction {
    return { type: 'SEND_NUMBER', payload: number };
}
```

We make a `ThunkAction` that dispatches this `NumberAction`.  It is a function that takes `dispatch` as an argument and returns a `Promise` for the action that it ultimately dispatches.

```
const myThunkAction1: ThunkAction<Promise<NumberAction>, any, any, NumberAction> = (dispatch): Promise<NumberAction> => {
    return axios.get('http://www.example.com')
        .then((res: AxiosResponse<any>) => {
            return 1;
        })
        .catch((err: AxiosError<any>) => {
            return 2;
        })
        .then(number => dispatch(sendNumber(number)));
}
```

We can `dispatch` this, but it returns the `ThunkAction` itself.  In other words, calling `dispatch` returns a function which takes `dispatch`.  So you cannot get anything meaningful from the return value of dispatching a thunk.

```
export function foo(dispatch: Dispatch<any, any, any>) {
    // still doesn't return Promise<number>, returns the ThunkAction
    const returned = dispatch(myThunkAction2);
    // can only get to Promise<number> by calling the returned thunk, which would re-dispatch the action
    const n: Promise<number> = returned(dispatch, () => {}, {});
    console.log(n);
}
```

[Second Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/KWzQem)

Comment: I can access neither of the two TS playground links. However, I think that calling `dispatch(myThankAction1)` returns a `Promise` and not the thunk itself. At least that's what I see in my tests, even though TS complains (but at the runtime, I do get a Promise). Like I said, I can't access the TS playground links so I can't play with your code. Also, on your last code block you have `dispatch(myThunkAction2)` (instead of `myThunkAction1`).

Comment: Anyway, I managed to reproduce it on a sandbox and posted another question specifically for the type question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64542213/274677

Comment: Oops I was playing with two versions of the thunk action, if you can't tell.  I haven't examined any runtime values.  The typescript definition is pretty clear that it returns the `ThunkAction` so I'm going off of that.